# Can Emacs be used as a text editor component inside another program?

Tags: python, emacs, spyder

I am specifically inspired by the Python IDE [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/). Here, for example IPython can be used as Python console for running programs. I was wondering if there could be any hope of modifying it to use Emacs as its "text editor window" as well, i.e. integrated into the GUI?

Answer (score 4):

(*Spyder dev here*) This is not possible right now, sorry. There are two options we are considering for the future:

1. Adding Emacs keybindings to our editor pane.
2. Adding a Qt widget that emulates a real terminal, where users can start Emacs and then use it as their editor.

Perhaps option 2 is the best one but I don't know of such a widget that is licensed BSD/MIT (the only licenses we can use).

Comment: Both options are useful. Emacs keybindings are always nice, and surely *much* easier to implement. However, unless you only use a stock-standard Emacs and a suitable sub-set of the editing commands and features available in Spyder, then keybindings alone can't possibly replace Emacs itself. So if you can't do (2), you could always consider doing (1) in the interim, and adding (2) in the future if possible.

Comment: Emacs key bindings would sure be nice.

Alternatively, could it be possible to implement it by having Spyder communicate with an open Emacs?

Answer (score 0):

I have manually modified the `keyboard shortcuts` to be consistent with `emacs`. It only takes a few minutes. I only modified the most frequently used key shortcuts..